# Django url/views

Tags: python, django, url, view

I have no idea why my code is not working? I am trying to return user_id, parse it to url and then open up details.html with that user_id. I realize this may not be the most efficient way of doing this. Any suggestions and help appreciated.

[As you can see from this image the first redirect works but it says there are no matching patterns.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFp2M.png)

```
@login_required(login_url="http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/")
def patientDetails(request):
return render(request, 'personalInfo/details.html', {})
@login_required(login_url="http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/")
def after_login(request):
return HttpResponseRedirect('/personalInfo/details/%d/'%request.user.id)

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^details/$', views.after_login, name='patient'),
url(r'^details/(?P<personalInfo_id>[0-9]+)/&', views.patientDetails),
]
```

[New Error. Tried a few different ways of referencing id such as user_id and](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tWZ5.png)

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: Just added image with error.

Comment: You may want to replace `&` with `$` at the your url pattern here `url(r'^details/(?P<personalInfo_id>[0-9]+)/&', views.patientDetails),`

Comment: Ye you're right thanks! Really should have seen that.. Have a new error now of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try removing /& from detais/id url and replace with /$

Change

```
url(r'^details/(?P<personalInfo_id>[0-9]+)/&', views.patientDetails),
```

with

```
url(r'^details/(?P<personalInfo_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.patientDetails),
```

Comment: You're right should have seen that. Now I have a new error I may be referencing the id wrong? Added a new pic with new error. Thanks

Comment: patientDetails(request, personalInfo_id):

Comment: Didn't think i'd need to put that in seeing that I wasn't using it in the definition. Thanks man it works now! :D

Comment: All these things are available in django documentation, Please go through it , create a basic app and you are good to go

Comment: Ye I tried going through it quickly I have a project due Friday week so just sorting out some last bits with users and profiles. Thanks